# how can I add animate.css to nuxt js app?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, animate.css

How do I install animate.css and have it working on my nuxtjs project? I have tried using the [animate.css installation guide](https://animate.style/) but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For npm users add animate.css on your project using this command
`npm i animate.css --save`

For yarn users
`yarn add animate.css`

Then add animate.css onto you `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  // ...
  css: ['animate.css/animate.min.css'] 
  // ...
}
```

Then use it in your HTML like so

```html
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce">
  An animated element
</h1>
```

Comment: `npm i animate.css` is shorter and doing exactly the same.